# What's the difference between complementary infinitives and infinitives as object?

Tags: grammar, american-english, infinitives, complements

Example:

> I forgot to lock the door.

Is "to lock" here a complementary infinitive or just an object?

Comment: It's all well and good closing a question because it already has three answers, but if those answers are either wrong or out of touch with modern grammar, then the OP will be misinformed.

Comment: ... As is often the case, there is a **tacit** assumption here that 'CGEL outranks any other analyses offered'. I find this unscholarly. The best approach is to add an answer at the claimed duplicate and let users vote on the different stances. Supported answers should receive proportionately more votes.

Comment: Nobody feels inclined to add another answer to a question that was posted over nine years ago and which has an answer that has been accepted by the then OP. Citing three other answers that more or less say the same thing is hardly giving users a balanced response.

Answer (score 2):

> *I forgot* [*to lock the door*].

The bracketed element is a complement, but it's not an object.

It's a catenative construction where "forgot" is the catenative verb and the infinitival clause "to lock the door" is its catenative complement.

Note that with only a few exceptions, objects of verbs consist of noun phrases, not clauses.